# It is not possible to close a webbrowser delphi messagebox

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control

I have the following problem. I am using the webbrowser delphi component, happens that accessing to the website this a messagebox appears to me but, I put a code in a timer so that when it appears that dialogue close it.

```
var
  hand: Thandle;
begin
  hand := findwindow(nil,'Windows Internet Explorer');
  SendMessage(hand, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
end;
```

but does not close the box when it appears. What is I to now occurred, leave a picture so that they understand a little bit the problem thanks. I hope the question is understood

[image]

Comment: You'd be better off avoiding the dialog in the first place. That's the approach I'd be looking for.

Answer (score 6):

The dialog does not close in response to the `WM_CLOSE` message because the dialog does not have a close button in its titlebar, as clearly shown in your screenshot.  This particular dialog is being displayed as a [Task Dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760441.aspx) via [`TaskDialogIndirect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544.aspx) without the [`TDF_ALLOW_DIALOG_CANCELLATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787473.aspx) flag specified:

> **TDF_ALLOW_DIALOG_CANCELLATION**
>   Indicates that the dialog should be able to be closed using Alt-F4, Escape, and **the title bar's close button** even if no cancel button is specified in either the dwCommonButtons or pButtons members.

Without that flag, the dialog can only be cancelled by clicking on one of the provided [Command Links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742403.aspx) buttons.  So you will have to enumerate the dialog's child controls until you find the button you are interested in, and then "click" it programmably, eg:

```
var
  Dlg, Sink, Btn: THandle;
begin
  Dlg := FindWindow('#32770', 'Windows Internet Explorer');
  //SendMessage(Dlg, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
  Dlg := FindWindowEx(Dlg, 0, 'DirectUIHWND', nil);
  Sink := FindWindowEx(Dlg, 0, 'CtrlNotifySink', nil);
  while Sink <> 0 do
  begin
    Btn := FindWindowEx(Sink, 0, 'BUTTON', nil);
    if Btn <> 0 then
    begin
      // TODO: verify this is actually the button you want...
      SendMessage(Btn, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
      Break;
    end;
    Sink := FindWindowEx(Dlg, Sink, 'CtrlNotifySink', nil);
  end;
end;
```

A word of caution about the [`BM_CLICK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775985.aspx) message:

> If the button is in a dialog box and the dialog box is not active, the **BM_CLICK** message might fail. To ensure success in this situation, call the [SetActiveWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646311.aspx) function to activate the dialog box before sending the **BM_CLICK** message to the button.